# VB IF statement to ask if NULL then apply default image instead

Tags: sql, vb.net

Inherited a VB website and am new to vb programming, so steep learning curve.

I have a site that searches and list all currently available cars in the UK for a leasing company.

the vehicle data is provided by an external comapany and links all the tech specs etc and images to a keyID. However...

If the vehicle has not been assigned an image it is not counted or displayed. I want to add an IF statement so that if the ImageId is Null then it will display a default 'awaiting image' jpg and would therefore still be listed to the public.

the page is http://www.carmyke.co.uk/search_prices.aspx with the 'Vans' dropping the most from the list.

I have included the code I think I need to update.

I think I need an IF statement for the .ImageId that if the SQL returns NULL then it uses a default image located in the same folder as defined by the appsettings

Hope this makes sense!?

<--- THE CODE --->

```
#Region "Methods"

    Private Function GetVehicle(ByVal SearchBy As SearchBy, _
                                ByVal SearchText As String) As Data.LeasingPrices.Vehicle
        Dim _Vehicle As New Data.LeasingPrices.Vehicle
        Try
            Dim _SQL As New Net.SQL
            _SQL.AppendSQL("SELECT TOP 1 * ")
            _SQL.AppendSQL("FROM vw_carmyke_Rates_Business ")
            _SQL.AppendSQL("LEFT OUTER JOIN carmyke_SpecialOffers ON vw_carmyke_Rates_Business.CVehicleId = carmyke_SpecialOffers.CVehicleId ")
            Select Case SearchBy
                Case Hydrate.SearchBy.Make
                    _SQL.AppendSQL("WHERE Make = @SearchText ")
                Case Hydrate.SearchBy.Model
                    _SQL.AppendSQL("WHERE MakeModel = @SearchText ")
                Case Hydrate.SearchBy.Derivative
                    _SQL.AppendSQL("WHERE MakeModelDerivative = @SearchText ")
            End Select
            _SQL.AppendSQL("ORDER BY Rental_48_40;")
            _SQL.AddParameter("@SearchText", SearchText, SqlDbType.VarChar)
            _SQL.ConnectReader()
            If _SQL.Validation.NoErrors Then
                If _SQL.Reader.Read() Then
                    With _Vehicle
                        .CVehicleId = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("CVehicleId").ToInteger()
                        .Van = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("BodyStyle").Contains("Van")
                        .Make = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("Make")
                        .Model = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("Model")
                        .Derivative = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("Derivative")
                        .ImageId = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("ImageId") & ".jpg"
                        .Co2 = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("Co2").ToInteger()
                        .P11d = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("P11d").ToDouble()
                        .Business = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("Business").ToBoolean()
                        .Personal = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("Personal").ToBoolean()
                        .Details = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("Details")
                        .OfferPrice = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("OfferPrice").ToDouble()
                        If .OfferPrice = 0 Then _
                            .OfferPrice = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("Offer_48_40").ToDouble()
                        If .OfferPrice = 0 Then _
                            .OfferPrice = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("Rental_48_40").ToDouble()
                        .Commercial = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("Commercial").ToBoolean()
                        .Offer_24_20 = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("Offer_24_20").ToDouble()
                        .Offer_24_40 = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("Offer_24_40").ToDouble()
                        .Offer_24_60 = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("Offer_24_60").ToDouble()
                        .Offer_36_30 = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("Offer_36_30").ToDouble()
                        .Offer_36_60 = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("Offer_36_60").ToDouble()
                        .Offer_36_90 = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("Offer_36_90").ToDouble()
                        .Offer_48_40 = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("Offer_48_40").ToDouble()
                        .Offer_48_80 = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("Offer_48_80").ToDouble()
                        .Offer_48_120 = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("Offer_48_120").ToDouble()
                        If .Offer_24_20 = -1 Then
                            .Rental_24_20 = 0
                        ElseIf .Offer_24_20 > 0 Then
                            .Rental_24_20 = .Offer_24_20
                        Else
                            .Rental_24_20 = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("Rental_24_20").ToDouble()
                        End If
                        If .Offer_24_40 = -1 Then
                            .Rental_24_40 = 0
                        ElseIf .Offer_24_40 > 0 Then
                            .Rental_24_40 = .Offer_24_40
                        Else
                            .Rental_24_40 = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("Rental_24_40").ToDouble()
                        End If
                        If .Offer_24_60 = -1 Then
                            .Rental_24_60 = 0
                        ElseIf .Offer_24_60 > 0 Then
                            .Rental_24_60 = .Offer_24_60
                        Else
                            .Rental_24_60 = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("Rental_24_60").ToDouble()
                        End If
                        If .Offer_36_30 = -1 Then
                            .Rental_36_30 = 0
                        ElseIf .Offer_36_30 > 0 Then
                            .Rental_36_30 = .Offer_36_30
                        Else
                            .Rental_36_30 = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("Rental_36_30").ToDouble()
                        End If
                        If .Offer_36_60 = -1 Then
                            .Rental_36_60 = 0
                        ElseIf .Offer_36_60 > 0 Then
                            .Rental_36_60 = .Offer_36_60
                        Else
                            .Rental_36_60 = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("Rental_36_60").ToDouble()
                        End If
                        If .Offer_36_90 = -1 Then
                            .Rental_36_90 = 0
                        ElseIf .Offer_36_90 > 0 Then
                            .Rental_36_90 = .Offer_36_90
                        Else
                            .Rental_36_90 = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("Rental_36_90").ToDouble()
                        End If
                        If .Offer_48_40 = -1 Then
                            .Rental_48_40 = 0
                        ElseIf .Offer_48_40 > 0 Then
                            .Rental_48_40 = .Offer_48_40
                        Else
                            .Rental_48_40 = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("Rental_48_40").ToDouble()
                        End If
                        If .Offer_48_80 = -1 Then
                            .Rental_48_80 = 0
                        ElseIf .Offer_48_80 > 0 Then
                            .Rental_48_80 = .Offer_48_80
                        Else
                            .Rental_48_80 = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("Rental_48_80").ToDouble()
                        End If
                        If .Offer_48_120 = -1 Then
                            .Rental_48_120 = 0
                        ElseIf .Offer_48_120 > 0 Then
                            .Rental_48_120 = .Offer_48_120
                        Else
                            .Rental_48_120 = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("Rental_48_120").ToDouble()
                        End If
                    End With
                Else
                    _Vehicle = Nothing
                End If
            Else
                _Vehicle = Nothing
            End If
            _SQL.DisconnectReader()
        Catch
            _Vehicle = Nothing
        End Try
        Return _Vehicle
    End Function

    Public Function Vehicle(ByVal SearchText As String) As Data.LeasingPrices.Vehicle
        Dim _Vehicle As New Data.LeasingPrices.Vehicle
        _Vehicle = GetVehicle(Hydrate.SearchBy.Derivative, SearchText)
        If _Vehicle Is Nothing Then
            _Vehicle = GetVehicle(Hydrate.SearchBy.Model, SearchText)
        End If
        If _Vehicle Is Nothing Then
            _Vehicle = GetVehicle(Hydrate.SearchBy.Make, SearchText)
        End If
        Return _Vehicle
    End Function

    Private Function GetSearchOption(ByVal SearchOption As String) As String
        Dim _GetSearchOption As String = ""
        Try
            If Not HttpContext.Current.Session(SearchOption) Is Nothing Then _
                _GetSearchOption = HttpContext.Current.Session(SearchOption)
        Catch
            _GetSearchOption = ""
        End Try
        Return _GetSearchOption
    End Function

    Public Function SearchOptions() As Data.LeasingPrices.SearchOptions
        Dim _SearchOptions As New Data.LeasingPrices.SearchOptions
        Try
            With _SearchOptions
                .FourByFour = GetSearchOption("FourByFour").ToBoolean()
                .CityCar = GetSearchOption("CityCar").ToBoolean()
                .Coupe = GetSearchOption("Coupe").ToBoolean()
                .Estate = GetSearchOption("Estate").ToBoolean()
                .Hatchback = GetSearchOption("Hatchback").ToBoolean()
                .MPV = GetSearchOption("MPV").ToBoolean()
                .Saloon = GetSearchOption("Saloon").ToBoolean()
                .Sports = GetSearchOption("Sports").ToBoolean()
                .Van = GetSearchOption("Van").ToBoolean()
                .RentalFrom = GetSearchOption("RentalFrom").ToInteger()
                .RentalTo = GetSearchOption("RentalTo").ToInteger()
                If .RentalFrom = 0 And .RentalTo = 0 Then
                    .RentalFrom = Data.LeasingPrices.SearchOptions.DefaultRentalFrom
                    .RentalTo = Data.LeasingPrices.SearchOptions.DefaultRentalTo
                End If
            End With
        Catch
            _SearchOptions = Nothing
        End Try
        Return _SearchOptions
    End Function

#End Region

#Region "Constructors"

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

#End Region

End Class

End Namespace
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the `Net.SQL` entity you're using, but it is usual to use something like the [Convert.IsDBNull Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.isdbnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check for a `NULL` database value.

An alternative is to use `COALESCE` in the query, like

```
SELECT TOP 1 [CVehicleId], ..more columns.., COALESCE([ImageId], 'AwaitingImage'), ..remaining columns..
```

You should really explicitly specify the columns, and put the column names in square brackets so that if you accidentally have a column name which happens to be an SQL keyword then it doesn't mistake it for a keyword.

Comment: Thanks- Not sure how I would add this the '.ImageId = _SQL.Reader.SQLString("ImageId") & ".jpg"'

Comment: Assuming you're referring to the SQL statement, if `[ImageId]` is `NULL` then it will return the string 'AwaitingImage', so you would end up with .ImageId = "AwaitingImage.jpg".

Comment: Sorry Andrew, I see how the sql would work but it how I would integrate it into the VB I have cuurently and work.

Comment: At the moment I have a work around of a T-SQL that I can put on a schedule to change all the NULL values in the relevant table to the jpg number (name) of my choice. But I would much prefer it to be at the site level

Comment: @BomberBrown Where you have `"SELECT TOP 1 * "`, replace it with the SQL I showed - not forgetting to list all the column names that you need. You could even get the number (name) from the web.config file so that you don't have to recompile the application just to change it.

Comment: Right, I see. I'll give it a try :)